# Python docx image rendering using docx template library

Tags: python-3.5, doc

I am trying to render a image to a docx template which has a jinja hook in it.

I am using inlineImage method from docx template using this I was able to render image it is opening in libreoffice writer but not in msword where it should be really using.

In msword a image is rendered but not shown just a blank area is shown.

I do even tried using the subdoc method it is also giving me same results.

Please do help me understand what am doing wrong.

I am using python-docx 0.8.7 and docxtemplate 0.5.17 library to achieve the result

I am bound to use these versions since docxtemplate enforced to use this version of python-docx

Comment: I was able to find the solution for the issue. The issue was I was using a temp file to render the inline doc when I remove that and used exact image path the inline method worked checked on a online preview mode , need to test it on real ms word hope that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer so that it may help others trying to achieve the same.

In my code i was using `NamedTemporaryFile(delete=None)` to create the image before I pass the value to inlineimage as `InlineImage(template, tmpfile.name)` Which was causing the Issue , I remodelled my logic to directly add the image after doing some resize based on image aspect ratio and send the path of the image instead of filename into the InlineImage method and it worked like a charm.